# Выделение произвольной области на яндекс картах(не полигон)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как сделать выделение произвольной области, как на domofond.ru? Удерживая нажатой левую кнопку мыши, двигаем курсор. Когда отпускаем, крайние точки замыкаются прямой, если фигура получилась незамкнутой.

Хочется реализовать так же, НЕ используя полигон и полилайн. Понятно, что в конечном итоге получится всё-равно полигон из очень маленьких отрезков.

Готовых решений не нашел. Все рекомендуют полигон, однако, повторюсь, он не подходит.

Допустим, я нарисую кривую на канвасе. Как разделить эту кривую на отрезки и как определить координаты точек на этой кривой? В какую сторону копать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть вы хотите рисовать так: нажимая левую кнопку мыши, двигать курсором по карте, выделяя за собой область, которую потом надо замкнуть? Или же Вы хотите тыкать мышью по карте, чтобы две точки замыкались, и образовывали  кривые?

Comment: Первый вариант. Удерживая нажатой левую кнопку мыши, двигаем курсор. Когда отпускаем, крайние точки замыкаются прямой, если фигура получилась незамкнутой.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Внимание - в конце сообщения - обновление!**

Если вы рисуете карандашом - то, по сути, это набор точек, или полилиния - только с маленьким шагом.

Как я понял проблема в аппроксимации этого набора точек. Есть такая библиотека - [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/), она может упростить набор точек в ломанную линию.

Работает это по алгоритму [Алгоритм Рамера — Дугласа — Пекера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

*Вот написал пример его работы - рисуйте на области канваса мышкой.*

```js
var canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),

  line = [];


var startX = 0,
  startY = 0;

function mouseDown(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  startX = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  startY = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

  canv.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  canv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);


  line = [];
  line.push({
    x: startX,
    y: startY
  });
}


function mouseMove(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
    y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();

  startX = x;
  startY = y;
  line.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
}


function mouseUp() {
  canv.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  canv.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

  aproximate();
}


function aproximate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  var res = simplify(line, 5);
  console.log(res);


  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(res[0].x, res[0].y);

  res.forEach(function(el) {
    ctx.lineTo(el.x, el.y);
  });
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

canv.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/simplify.js"></script>
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
```

## Обновление: Набросок кода для рисования подобных линий на карте

*Извиняюсь, что не очень красивый код - торопился.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var Map = (function() {

  ymaps.ready(init);
  var myMap;

  function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [57.5262, 38.3061], // Углич
      zoom: 11
    }, {
      balloonMaxWidth: 200,
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    addPolygon()
  }


  function convert(coords) {
    var projection = myMap.options.get('projection');

    return coords.map(function(el) {
      var c = projection.fromGlobalPixels(myMap.converter.pageToGlobal([el.x, el.y]), myMap.getZoom());
      return c;
    });
  }

  function addPolygon(coord) {
    var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [coord],
      },
    }, {
      fillColor: '#00FF00',
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      opacity: 0.5,
      strokeWidth: 3
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
  }

  return {
    addPolygon: addPolygon,
    convert: convert
  };
})();

//----------------------

var canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),

  line = [];

var map = document.getElementById('map');
canv.width = map.offsetWidth;
canv.height = map.offsetWidth;


var startX = 0,
  startY = 0;

function mouseDown(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  startX = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  startY = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

  canv.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  canv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);


  line = [];
  line.push({
    x: startX,
    y: startY
  });
}


function mouseMove(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
    y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();

  startX = x;
  startY = y;
  line.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
}

function mouseUp() {
  canv.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  canv.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

  aproximate();
}

function aproximate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  var res = simplify(line, 5);
  res = Map.convert(res);
  Map.addPolygon(res);
}

canv.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/simplify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Это обязательно пригодится. Хотелось бы понять,  как теперь преобразовать полученные точки в координаты на yandex карте.

Comment: В этом должен помочь класс [map.Converter](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/map.Converter-docpage/)

Comment: Вот вам еще пример: http://jsfiddle.net/5bus86mw/ . Правда вам он наверное не понадобится, т.к. рисовать непрерывную кривую вам лучше на наложенный поверх карты canvas.

Comment: @Rjazhenka я добавил код в конце - он вроде реализует то, что вы хотели.

Comment: Александр, отлично! Спасибо за решение

Comment: Александр, огромное спасибо за Ваш ответ! Он очень помог мне. Но не могли бы подсказать как менять стиль рисуемой линии? К сожалению я не могу понять где это сделать :(

Comment: Если вы про яндекс карты - то давно уже не работал, не припомню, есть про canvas то `context.strokeStyle`

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, вам подойдет Polyline ([документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Polyline-docpage/)).
Очень просто будет получить координаты всех точек и обработать их как вам угодно.

Comment: К сожалению, этот инструмент не подходит для решения поставленный задачи. Нужно иметь возможность "рисовать". Как карандашом обвести область.

Comment: А что вам мешает обводить как карандашом?

Answer (score 1):

Изначально хотел предложить повесить канвас поверх карт, потом увидел, что **polyline** позволяет получить желаемый результат, если конечно нет необходимости именно как карандашом проводить линии.

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/at138o5y/

```
<div id="map" style="width:800px; height:600px"></div>
```

Скрипт:

```
var polyline;

ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.426541,37.768788], 
            zoom: 13
        });

     myMap.controls                
        .add('zoomControl')               
        .add('typeSelector')                
        .add('mapTools')


    polyline = new ymaps.Polyline([], {}, {});

    myMap.geoObjects.add(polyline);
    polyline.editor.startEditing();
    polyline.editor.startDrawing();

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу, но это решение не подходит. Я уточнил в вопросе, что нужно нарисовать кривую, нажав левую кнопку мыши и не отпуская ее.